# Problems importing cymunk

Tags: python, ubuntu, metadata, kivy, setup.py

I downloaded cymunk to use it on kivent_cymunk and as i tried to import it got following error:

```
>>> import cymunk
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cymunk/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
     from .cymunk import *
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cymunk/cymunk/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
     from .cymunk import *
 ImportError: No module named cymunk
```

So python finds cymunk in my main.py but it doesn't find cymunk in cymunk.**init**().

Im am working on ubuntu 14.04 and i installed cymunk like this:

```
daniel@daniel-K54C:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cymunk$ sudo python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
skipping 'cymunk/cymunk.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)


daniel@daniel-K54C:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cymunk$ sudo python setup.py check
    running check
    warning: check: missing required meta-data: version, url


daniel@daniel-K54C:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cymunk$ sudo python setup.py install
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    skipping 'cymunk/cymunk.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    running install_lib
    running install_egg_info
    Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cymunk-0.0.0.egg-info
    Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cymunk-0.0.0.egg-info
```

As you probably recognized the required meat data is missing.
I don't know what that is and if this is causing my problem.

What am i doing wrong? And what can i do to get cymunk to work?
I appreciate any help, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your build output, you incorrectly extracted the "cymunk" source into /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cymunk .

You should not extract sources into /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/..., in this case, the source directory "name" is colliding with the library name that is installed with site-packages.

Fix:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cymunk
extract and rebuild from your home dir
```

Comment: thank you very much! you saved me a lot of time dude.